# Tableview creates five rows on one row?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with a custom cell that I have told should give me 5 cells in return of this custom cell. The question now is that I am running the app and getting five rows on one row. I have changed from default size of cell to custom but that is nearly the only thing I have done. So now I wonder what can create this kind of problem?

[image: Broken tableView image]

The code of my tableView looks like this.

[image: swift editor]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "theoryCell") as! theoryTVC

    return cell
}
```

Comment: That looks normal. It is creating 5 rows. The white spacing you see is just a rendering bug on the simulator. If you try it on a physical device it'll be fine or try to adjust the screen size of it (CMD+1, CMD+2)

Comment: but i have put a size of a 150 and in the editor it looks correct but it looks very bad when i start the app

Comment: Did you set proper Constraints in your  custom cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is you are using custom cell with custom height but you are not setting height for row in table view method.

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 100.0 //Choose your custom row height
}
```

Comment: Thanks i thought that only the cell height had to be changed but apparently not. thank you so much for the help though and have a nice day

Comment: Welcome!You can ping me though if you need help again in future on urgent.Thanks!

Comment: @J.Doe2 you can set his answer also in Storyboard. You now have dynamic height for each cell. This means that each cell has a height that is equal to the instrictic content size :)